# Is there a way to check inputs against lists using matches?

Tags: python, list, input, match

I need a way to test a single multiple list items against a single input/var (preferably with matches) and have a different function be performed based on which list item matches that input/var.

Currently I am using:

```
match I:

 case List[0]:
  input 1

 case List[1]:
  input 2
```

But it keeps returning an error that `case` cannot contain a built-in mutable sequence, which is the reason I switched from a ton of if - elif functions.

Comment: You can use the `index` method of a list to find the index of a given value and then e.g. use this index in the `case`s.

Comment: How big is your list?  If it's a large one, it does not make sense to use ```match``` then.  Why cannot just use the *input value*?

Comment: "which is the reason I switched from a ton of if - elif functions." - I can't understand the reasoning (putting aside the wrong terminology). Won't there be just as many `case`s as there were `if`/`elif`/`else`?

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly change the order of matching for an index. For example:

```py
x = 'a'
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
match l.index(x):
   case 0:
      print("input 1")
   case 1:
      print("input 1")
   case 2:
      print("input 1")
```

With this approach your list might have dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the index of a list object against the input, I landed on comparing the input directly to each object that was in the list as the list didn't need to be amended while running.

```
match x:

case option1:
 print("option 1")

case option2:
 print("option 2")
```